# Issue with json data parsing

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, typescript, object

I have the following data:

```js
{
  "Result": "{\"Plot\":{\"Series\":[{\"color\":\"green\",\"title\":\"Temperature Gradient\",\"x_unit\":\"Temperature (°F)\",\"y_unit\":\"Depth (ft)\",\"dashStyle\":\"Solid\",\"lineType\":\"spline\",\"xAxisOnTop\":true,\"x_values\":\"80,90.78,101.56,112.35,123.13,133.91,144.69,155.47,166.26,177.04,199.96,210.63,220\",\"y_values\":\"0,-404.6,-809.2,-1213.8,-1618.4,-2023,-2427.6,-2832.2,-3236.8,-3641.4,-4046,-4502,-4825\"}]},\"OperatingTagResult\":null}",
  "StatusCode": 200
}
```

And I want to get two new variables.

1. `{\"Plot\":{\"Series\":[{\"color\":\"green\",\"title\":\"Temperature Gradient\",\"x_unit\":\"Temperature (°F)\",\"y_unit\":\"Depth (ft)\",\"dashStyle\":\"Solid\",\"lineType\":\"spline\",\"xAxisOnTop\":true,\"x_values\":\"80,90.78,101.56,112.35,123.13,133.91,144.69,155.47,166.26,177.04,199.96,210.63,220\",\"y_values\":\"0,-404.6,-809.2,-1213.8,-1618.4,-2023,-2427.6,-2832.2,-3236.8,-3641.4,-4046,-4502,-4825\"}]},\"OperatingTagResult\":null}`
2. Just `200` from "StatusCode"

How can I implement this?

I got next error when use json parse:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: in js: `var obj = JSON.parse(JSON_STRING); var variable1 = obj.Result; var variable2 = obj.StatusCode`.

Comment: What is the "issue"? That should be pretty straightforward!

Comment: Did you even try to research JSON parsing?

Comment: yes. But I have error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1:

Comment: It looks like you could benefit from `JSON.parse(data.Result)` but post a [mcve] so we can see how you read the strings

Comment: @MaxKarpovets you should provide that in your question. The javascript or typescript you have currently and the error you are receiving.

Comment: @MaxKarpovets You still did not provide a js code which raises that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a variable and use dot notation to access "Result" and "StatusCode" properties:

```
var income = {"Result":"{\"Plot\":{\"Series\":[{\"color\":\"green\",\"title\":\"Temperature Gradient\",\"x_unit\":\"Temperature (°F)\",\"y_unit\":\"Depth (ft)\",\"dashStyle\":\"Solid\",\"lineType\":\"spline\",\"xAxisOnTop\":true,\"x_values\":\"80,90.78,101.56,112.35,123.13,133.91,144.69,155.47,166.26,177.04,199.96,210.63,220\",\"y_values\":\"0,-404.6,-809.2,-1213.8,-1618.4,-2023,-2427.6,-2832.2,-3236.8,-3641.4,-4046,-4502,-4825\"}]},\"OperatingTagResult\":null}","StatusCode":200}

var result = income.Result; // {"Plot":{"Series":[{"color":"green", ...
var status = income.StatusCode; // 200
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var jsonOBJ = {
      "Result": "{\"Plot\":{\"Series\":[{\"color\":\"green\",\"title\":\"Temperature Gradient\",\"x_unit\":\"Temperature (°F)\",\"y_unit\":\"Depth (ft)\",\"dashStyle\":\"Solid\",\"lineType\":\"spline\",\"xAxisOnTop\":true,\"x_values\":\"80,90.78,101.56,112.35,123.13,133.91,144.69,155.47,166.26,177.04,199.96,210.63,220\",\"y_values\":\"0,-404.6,-809.2,-1213.8,-1618.4,-2023,-2427.6,-2832.2,-3236.8,-3641.4,-4046,-4502,-4825\"}]},\"OperatingTagResult\":null}",
      "StatusCode": 200
    };
    
    console.log(jsonOBJ.Result);
    console.log(jsonOBJ.StatusCode);
```

you don't need to parse your json beacuse is already a jsonObject. Try to parse it - `JSON.parse(jsonString)` and then get the value and you will find the error that you have

Answer (score 0):

First define a variable to your json;

```
var Temperature = {"Result":"{\"Plot\":{\"Series\":[{\"color\":\"green\",\"title\":\"Temperature Gradient\",\"x_unit\":\"Temperature (°F)\",\"y_unit\":\"Depth (ft)\",\"dashStyle\":\"Solid\",\"lineType\":\"spline\",\"xAxisOnTop\":true,\"x_values\":\"80,90.78,101.56,112.35,123.13,133.91,144.69,155.47,166.26,177.04,199.96,210.63,220\",\"y_values\":\"0,-404.6,-809.2,-1213.8,-1618.4,-2023,-2427.6,-2832.2,-3236.8,-3641.4,-4046,-4502,-4825\"}]},\"OperatingTagResult\":null}","StatusCode":200}

then call the required filed you are required.

var income = {"Result":"{\"Plot\":{\"Series\":[{\"color\":\"green\",\"title\":\"Temperature Gradient\",\"x_unit\":\"Temperature (°F)\",\"y_unit\":\"Depth (ft)\",\"dashStyle\":\"Solid\",\"lineType\":\"spline\",\"xAxisOnTop\":true,\"x_values\":\"80,90.78,101.56,112.35,123.13,133.91,144.69,155.47,166.26,177.04,199.96,210.63,220\",\"y_values\":\"0,-404.6,-809.2,-1213.8,-1618.4,-2023,-2427.6,-2832.2,-3236.8,-3641.4,-4046,-4502,-4825\"}]},\"OperatingTagResult\":null}","StatusCode":200}

alert(Temperature.Result);
alert(Temperature.StatusCode);
```